# RestTemplate spring boot returns null

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Please help. I have following code:

```
CheckResponse checkResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(webServiceUrl,checkTaxesWrapper, CheckResponse.class);
```

Where CheckResponse is my POJO that looks like this:

```
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonPropertyOrder(
            {
                    "errorCode",
                    "errorMessage",
                    "merchantTransationId",
                    "totalFee",
                    "numberOfWarrants",
                    "warrantList"

            }
    )
    public class CheckResponse
    {
        private String errorCode;
        private String errorMessage;
        private String merchantTransactionId;
        private String totalFee;
        private String numberOfWarrants;
        private List<Warrant>warrantList;

        private double taxSum;
        private double total;

        public double getTaxSum() {
            return taxSum;
        }

        public void setTaxSum(double taxSum) {
            this.taxSum = taxSum;
        }

        public double getTotal() {
            return total;
        }

        public void setTotal(double total) {
            this.total = total;
        }

        public List<Warrant> getWarrantList() {
            return warrantList;
        }

        public void setWarrantList(List<Warrant> warrantList) {
            this.warrantList = warrantList;
        }

        public String getErrorCode() {
            return errorCode;
        }

        public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
            this.errorCode = errorCode;
        }

        public String getErrorMessage() {
            return errorMessage;
        }

        public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
            this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        }

        public String getMerchantTransactionId() {
            return merchantTransactionId;
        }

        public void setMerchantTransactionId(String merchantTransactionId) {
            this.merchantTransactionId = merchantTransactionId;
        }

        public String getTotalFee() {
            return totalFee;
        }

        public void setTotalFee(String totalFee) {
            this.totalFee = totalFee;
        }

        public String getNumberOfWarrants() {
            return numberOfWarrants;
        }

        public void setNumberOfWarrants(String numberOfWarrants) {
            this.numberOfWarrants = numberOfWarrants;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CheckResponse{" +
                    "errorCode='" + errorCode + '\'' +
                    ", errorMessage='" + errorMessage + '\'' +
                    ", merchantTransactionId='" + merchantTransactionId + '\'' +
                    ", totalFee='" + totalFee + '\'' +
                    ", numberOfWarrants='" + numberOfWarrants + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

and as you can see I have Warrant POJO that looks like this:

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonPropertyOrder(
            {
                    "amount",
                    "personalId",
                    "benRefModel",
                    "ordPartyRefNumber",
                    "sourceAccount",
                    "purpose",
                    "benAddress",
                    "actualAmount",
                    "benPlace",
                    "ordPartyPlace",
                    "nacinPlacanja",
                    "transactionID",
                    "transactionType",
                    "reservationId",
                    "urgency",
                    "purposeCode",
                    "benRefNumber",
                    "benName",
                    "ordPartyTime",
                    "ordPartyAddress",
                    "currency",
                    "currencyDate",
                    "destinationAmount",
                    "ordPartyRefModel",
                    "info"
            }
    )
    public class Warrant {
        @JsonProperty("amount")
        private String amount;
        @JsonProperty("personalId")
        private String personalId;
        @JsonProperty("benRefModel")
        private String benRefModel;
        @JsonProperty("ordPartyRefNumber")
        private static final String ordPartyRefNumber="";
        @JsonProperty("sourceAccount")
        private static final String sourceAccount="";

        @JsonProperty("purpose")
        private String purpose;
        @JsonProperty("benAddress")
        private String benAddress;
        @JsonProperty("actualAmount")
        private String actualAmount;
        @JsonProperty("benPlace")
        private String benPlace;



        @JsonProperty("ordPartyPlace")
        private  String ordPartyPlace;
        @JsonProperty("nacinPlacanja")
        private String nacinPlacanja="E";
        @JsonProperty("transactionID")
        private String transactionID;
        @JsonProperty("transactionType")
        private  String transactionType;
        @JsonProperty("reservationId")
        private String reservationId;
        @JsonProperty("urgency")
        private  String urgency;
        @JsonProperty("purposeCode")
        private  String purposeCode="253";
        @JsonProperty("benRefNumber")
        private String benRefNumber;
        @JsonProperty("benName")
        private String benName;
        @JsonProperty("ordPartyName")
        private String ordPartyName;
        @JsonProperty("ordPartyAddress")
        private String ordPartyAddress;
        @JsonProperty("currency")
        private String currency="941";
        @JsonProperty("currencyDate")
        private String currencyDate;
        @JsonProperty("destinationAccount")
        private String destinationAccount;
        @JsonProperty("ordPartyRefModel")
        private  String ordPartyRefModel="";
        @JsonProperty("info")
        private  String info;
    //getters and setters..
    }
```

I used interceptor that logs outgoing requests and resulting responses. I see fllowing response:

```
 2018-02-12 12:47:50.798  WARN 1732 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] r.e.p.logging.LoggingRequestInterceptor  : ============================response begin==========================================
    2018-02-12 12:47:50.798  WARN 1732 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] r.e.p.logging.LoggingRequestInterceptor  : Status code  : 200
    2018-02-12 12:47:50.798  WARN 1732 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] r.e.p.logging.LoggingRequestInterceptor  : Status text  : OK
    2018-02-12 12:47:50.798  WARN 1732 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] r.e.p.logging.LoggingRequestInterceptor  : Headers      : {Date=[Mon, 12 Feb 2018 11:47:50 GMT], Server=[Apache], Keep-Alive=[timeout=5, max=100], Connection=[Keep-Alive], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=utf-8]}
    2018-02-12 12:47:50.798  WARN 1732 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] r.e.p.logging.LoggingRequestInterceptor  : Response body: 

{"errorCode":"00","errorMessage":"Approved","merchantTransationId":"201802121247500094RLk","totalFee":50,"numberOfWarrants":1,"warrantList":[{"transactionID":"33519e05-ab21-4a2e-9fdd-f1bfd1104691","trnFee":50,"transactionId":63496411,"trnMessage":"","trnStatus":1,"realValueDate":"2018-02-12 11:47:50"}]}
```

But resttemplate returns null.. I don't know why.. This is stack trace:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at rs.euprava.payment.controller.rest.RestRequestsController.checkSelectedTaxes(RestRequestsController.java:268)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I appreciate any help.Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the NullPointerException at rs.euprava.payment.controller.rest.RestRequestsController.checkSelectedTaxes(RestRequestsController.java:268) ?

Comment: Yes,I have checked..First tried to determinate if the checkResponse object is null,so I added this line of code : if(checkResponse==null){LOG.warn("Response is null")},and I can see that output in console..So that object is null,but I dont know why.. p.s. Sorry for my english,i hope you understand what i want to say :)

Comment: I think one of the fields is causing an error. You might want have a simple response for now with just one or two fields and if that works add one or two fields again until you get an error.

Comment: I also thought that there is some error with fields,but when i do following:String checkResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(webServiceUrl, checkTaxesWrapper, String.class); I also get null value for checkResponse object

Comment: @Ivan I thought this is a response you got which is not null. `{"errorCode":"00","errorMessage":"Approved","merchantTransationId...`

Comment: If you don't show us what happens at `rs.euprava.payment.controller.rest.RestRequestsController.checkSelectedTaxes` it will be difficult to assist you... I don't think the error is related to rest template since you received a response with a 200 status code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you review your pojo json annotations for Warrant? I think they should match the ones below:

```
@JsonProperty("transactionID")
private String transactionID;

@JsonProperty("trnFee")
private Integer trnFee;

@JsonProperty("transactionId")
private Integer transactionId;

@JsonProperty("trnMessage")
private String trnMessage;

@JsonProperty("trnStatus")
private Integer trnStatus;

@JsonProperty("realValueDate")
private String realValueDate;
```

Comment: I changed so my Warrant POJO looks like this  : @JsonProperty("transactionID")
    private String transactionID;
    @JsonProperty("trnFee")
    private Integer trnFee;
    @JsonProperty("transactionId")
    private Integer transactionId;

    @JsonProperty("trnMessage")
    private String trnMessage;

    @JsonProperty("trnStatus")
    private Integer trnStatus;
    @JsonProperty("realValueDate")
    private String realValueDate;   but that didnt help..Im still getting null pointer exception

Comment: Yes, my annotations match annotations from your answer,but i'm still getting same exception.. I tried to use   String  response =  restTemplate.postForObject(webServiceUrl,checkTaxesWrapper,String.class);just to check response from rest service without creating any java object,but I'm still getting same exception

Comment: What about `CheckResponse` class, did you also annotated it with `@JsonProperty` ?

Comment: Yes,you can see how my CheckResponse class looks like,i wrote it at the beginnig of my question.I changed totalFee field to be type int,and numberOfWarrants field also to be type of int,but still no luck..The thing is,I dont understand when i use just this line of code: String response = restTemplate.postForObject(webServiceUrl,checkTaxesWrapper,String.class),so without any deserilazition json to java object,Im still getting null value for response string althought I see correct response in log..

Comment: your `CheckResponse` does not have @JsonProperty annotations as per your question above. I am not confident that your POJO is annotated to match the actual response you are getting.

Comment: Yes but if there is no @JsonProperty annotation I think Spring will use provided field name.. But as far as I can see,the problem is not in POJO,beacause im getting null response from restTemplate even in this case: String response= restTemplate.postForObject(webServiceUrl,checkTaxesWrapper,String.class)..

Comment: Ok, then maybe the type is wrong as in `totalFee` and `numberOfWarrants` being Integer and not String. I insist about your POJO because  think the response you see in logs is before deserialization, therefore it could be a problem while converting.

Comment: Yes,i understand. I tried to replace that field types to string type but still doesnt work..